# rails 3 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord, sqlite

I am making a search to my index.html.erb and it gives me an error.
This is my index.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All configurations') %>
<h1>All configurations</h1>

<%= form_tag conf_show_all_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<table class="pretty" border="1" cellpadding="10">  
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable("machine_name",       "M.Name")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("machine_brand",      "M.Brand")      %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("machine_model",      "M.Model")      %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("control_unit_brand", "C.Unit Brand") %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("control_unit_model", "C.Unit Model") %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("tool_axis_x",        "Axis X")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("tool_axis_y",        "Axis Y")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("tool_axis_z",        "Axis Z")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("rotary_axis_number", "R.Axis")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("linear_axis_number", "L.Axis")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "description"                         %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("name",               "Developer")    %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "updated_at"                          %></th>
  </tr>  

  <% for conf in @confs %>  
  <tr class="<%= cycle('oddrow', 'evenrow') -%>">
    <td><%= link_to conf.machine_name, conf %></td>
    <td><%= conf.machine_brand %></td>
    <td><%= conf.machine_model %></td>
    <td><%= conf.control_unit_brand %></td>
    <td><%= conf.control_unit_model %></td>
    <td><%= conf.tool_axis_x %></td>
    <td><%= conf.tool_axis_y %></td>
    <td><%= conf.tool_axis_z %></td>
    <td><%= conf.rotary_axis_number %></td>
    <td><%= conf.linear_axis_number %></td>
    <td><%= conf.description %></td>
    <td><%= conf.developer.name unless conf.developer_id.blank? %></td>
    <td><%= conf.updated_at %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @confs %>
```

This is search in conf.rb:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    q = "%#{search}%"
    where('machine_name LIKE ? OR 
           machine_brand LIKE ? OR 
           machine_model LIKE ? OR 
           control_unit_brand LIKE ? OR 
           control_unit_model LIKE ? OR 
           tool_axis_x LIKE ? OR 
           tool_axis_y LIKE ? OR 
           tool_axis_z LIKE ? OR 
           rotary_axis_number LIKE ? OR 
           linear_axis_number LIKE ? OR 
           description LIKE ? OR
           developer_id LIKE ? OR
           updated_at LIKE ? OR',
          q,q,q,q,q,q,q,q,q,q,q,q,q)
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

This is sortable method in application_helper.rb:

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)  
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = (column == sort_column) ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"  
    link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
end
```

Finally, this is the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Confs#index
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: name: SELECT  "confs".* FROM "confs"  ORDER BY name asc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
Extracted source (around line #30)
```

Line 30 is this:

> 

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, search in `conf.rb` should `updated_at LIKE ?'` instead of `updated_at LIKE ? OR'` this was one syntax error. About question, I changed `sort_column` in `confs_controller.rb` from `...params[:sort] : "name"` to `...params[:sort] : "machine_name"`

Comment: @mehow, I was confused that time I think and thought this was the answer, I updated my answer, it is real now, thanks for warning